Dockerized cron job cannot find package
(Linux intended requests) I develop the repository in [1]. It must perform a cron job with database population. For now, I focus myself into developing the scripting for cron-job. As you can see, both docker assets docker-compose.yaml and Dockerfile are below. I developed a Makefile to bring ease to life: you can use make build && make up.  Oftentimes, the container stalls, which requires command run docker inspect cron-task | jq -r '.[0].State.Pid' | sudo xargs kill, alias is make kill-cron (install jq first, with command run sudo apt install jq).
docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  cron-task:
    image: cron-task
    container_name: cron-task
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
    
networks:
  cron_net:

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.12-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

# Copy your application code
COPY .env .
COPY backend/ .
COPY scripts/ .

# Set env variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONPATH="/backend"

# Install dependencies:
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install uv
RUN pip install uv
RUN uv pip install -r requirements.txt --system

# Install the required packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install cron python3 python3-pip postgresql-client

# Cron jobs
RUN echo '* * * * * bash /app/scripts/cron_task.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1' > cron-config

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 cron-config

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab cron-config

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD echo "starting" && \
    echo "continuing" && \
    (cron) && \
    echo "tailing..." && \
    : >> /var/log/cron.log && \
    tail -f /var/log/cron.log

[1] https://github.com/brunolnetto/db-cron-docker
Currently, the container log outputs of command run is docker logs -f cron-task is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythonjsonlogger'. As you can see by command run docker exec -it cron-task pip list | grep pythonjsonlogger, the required package is there (output is python-json-logger 2.0.7).
I am indeed able to fix the import issue placing pip install -r requirements.txt before the call python3 ..., but it is not very elegant from my perspective.
It leaves without further steps.

There's a couple of things I'd try cleaning up here.  PYTHONPATH points at a nonexistent directory, but you almost never need to set it (the current directory is usually there by default).  You should just run the cron daemon in the foreground CMD cron -f, and you usually shouldn't overwrite the application code with volumes: (you shouldn't need to override working_dir: either).  If you clean it up, does it work better?  Does docker compose run cron-task /app/script/cron_task.sh work to run the script directly without involving cron?

I fixed the issue with import by adding the command run pip install -r requirements.txt before the command python3. It is not elegant though. Can you guess a more performatic way to perform it?
